# generating random numbers using srand

Tags: c++, c

I want to generate five random numbers each time using srand() function within the range 1 to 10. Here is a sample program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define size 10
 int main()
 {
   int A[5];
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
      A[i]=srand()%size      
   }
}
```

But I am getting an error saying too few arguments for the function srand(). What will be the solution?

Comment: If it says there are too few arguments, what do you think the solution is? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand

Comment: `rand` is the function you are looking for. `srand` seeds `rand`.

Comment: @bku_drytt: but supplying an argument will not fix this. `srand` is not supposed to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`srand`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand) sets the seed for [`rand`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand), the pseudo-random number generator.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>   /* Unused header */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For `rand` and `srand` */
#include <time.h>   /* For `time` */

#define size 10

int main()
{
  int A[5];

  srand(time(NULL)); /* Seed `rand` with the current time */

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    A[i] = rand() % size; // `rand() % size` generates a number between 0 (inclusive) and 10 (exclusive)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have to use `std::rand()` not `std::srand()` but before use that, you have to feed unsigned value using`std::srand()`. Something like initiation.

Look at the std::srand() referance http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand

```
/*Seeds the pseudo-random number generator used by std::rand() with the value seed.
If rand() is used before any calls to srand(), rand() behaves as if it was seeded with srand(1). Each time rand() is seeded with srand(), it must produce the same sequence of values.    
srand() is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.
*/

    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>


        int main() 
        {
            std::srand(std::time(0)); //use current time as seed for random generator
            int random_variable = std::rand();
            std::cout << "Random value on [0 " << RAND_MAX << "]: " 
                      << random_variable << '\n';
        }
```